# Resizing "extended" partition on MBR formatted HD

Tags: partitioning

My desktop has an SSD formatted as MBR.  The desktop is a multiboot system (Win10 and UBUNTU).  Win10 is updated with the latest version (1803).

The SSD contains partitions (in sequence of appearance)

1. "systems reserved" (500MB)
2. Win10 "C:" disk (49 GB)
3. Win10 "Diagnostics" (820 MB), and
4. Extended partition that allocated the remainder of the space.

In the Extended partition there are:

1. an Ubuntu 17.04 ext3 partition (38GB)
2. an Ubuntu swapfile (8GB), and
3. an "unallocated" space of the remaining space (128GB)

I need to expand the "C:" partition, but can't do that ("Resize/Move" greyed out) using Windows tools, probably because all unused diskspace (128GB) is in the Extended partition.  The Win10 tools do not allow me to resize (reduce) the "Extended" partition.  So I decided to reduce the Extended partition using a live UBUNTU system and then use Gparted (as recommended on some forums).

After updating the partitions (6 steps), Gparted showed me the following structure:

1. "systems reserved" (500MB)
2. a Win10 "C:" disk (79 GB)
3. Win10 "Diagnostics" (820 MB), and
4. Extended partition that allocated the remainder of the available space.

In the Extended partition there are:

1. an Ubuntu 17.04 ext3 partition (38GB)
2. an Ubuntu smapfile (8GB), and
3. an "unallocated space of the remaining space (98GB)

Gparted in UBUNTU LIVE worked fine.  Also after restarting the UBUNTU LIVE system Gparted shows me the new structure (as expected) of the partitions.

Then I rebooted the PC from the SSD and started UBUNTU: it works fine and shows the partition structure as changed.

I reboot the PC again and start Win10.  Win10 works fine.  EASEUS Partition Manager shows the partitions as Gparted did (changed).  Windows disk manager however shows the partitions as they were BEFORE I changed them with Gparted.  I assume that that demonstrates that Win10 disk manager got the info about the partitions from somewhere else, not from the partition table?

In Win10 Disk Manager I click "refresh" (hoping that the partition structure on my screen would be updated to reflect the current layout of the SSD), but Win10 BSOD's and Win10 becomes unbootable (during startup msgs tell me that there is something wrong with my SSD).

After this I still can boot the Desktop and work with UBUNTU.  Also I can boot into Win10, but during the start of Win10 it BSOD's again.  Because the boot itself seems to work fine, I conclude that the GRUB bootloader is still OK.

Can a specialist here tell me how I can make Win10 Disk Manager show the partitions as they are after I modified them with Gparted, and that without making the PC unusable?  Or if that's not possible, how I can achieve what I want to do (= increasing the size of the "C:" disk)?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Tools are not really usable to manage partitions.
I use this tool for such actions (it's free): [Download Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html)